# How can I make this c++ program faster?

Tags: c++, runtime

I am trying to sort strings using merge sort and standard string comparison. The problem is, this program is very slow as is. I am exceeding runtime expectations when I am attempting to check my solution. Is there a way I can use some other data structure to do the same thing but be accessed faster? Here is the code. Thank you for your help.

Edit: I understand that using sort() rather than my own merge sort algorithm will be faster, but my requirement states to use merge sort. The problem is exceeding runtime requirements on SPOJ.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void MergeSortA(int low , int high);
void MergeA(int low ,int mid ,int high);

string stringData[50000];
int main()
{
    int testCases;
    int linesInTestCase;

    scanf("%d", &testCases);
    while(testCases--)
    {
        scanf("%d", &linesInTestCase);
        for(int i = 0; i < linesInTestCase; ++i)
            cin >> stringData[i];

        // Sort the data
        MergeSortA(0, linesInTestCase - 1);

        // Print array of strings one by one
        for(int i = 0; i < linesInTestCase; ++i) {
            cout << stringData[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void MergeSortA(int low , int high)
{
    int mid = 0;
    if(low < high)
    {
        mid = ((low+high)/2);
        MergeSortA(low , mid);
        MergeSortA(mid+1,high);
        MergeA(low,mid,high);
    }
}
void MergeA(int low ,int mid , int high)
{
    int i = low, j = mid+1 , k = low;
    string Temp[50000];

    while(i <= mid && j <= high) {
        if( stringData[i] < stringData[j] ) {
            Temp[k].assign(stringData[i]);
            i++;
        }
        else {
            Temp[k].assign(stringData[j]);
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    if(i > mid ) {
        for(int h = j ;h <= high ; h++ ) {
            Temp[k].assign(stringData[h]);
            k++;
        }
    }
    else
        for(int h = i; h<= mid ; h++ ) {
            Temp[k].assign(stringData[h]);
            k++;
        }

    // Copy from low to high
    for(int l = low; l <= high ; l++) {
        stringData[l].assign(Temp[l]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the average size of the strings? If the size is high, copying them takes time. Using `move` or `swap` should be more efficient.

Comment: You might want to consider using a different algorithm. Using `std::sort()` would substantially reduce the amount of code needed, and offers complexity that is comparable (if not better) than a merge sort.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent-the-wheel because you are trying to understand the underlying algorithm? If not, there are more standard facilities available for implementing mergesort easier.

Comment: I am not necessarily trying to reinvent the wheel here, but I am supposed to use mergesort

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated that this is SPOJ problem, I will try not alter your structure of your program, However, there is real bottleneck here:

```
void MergeA(int low ,int mid , int high)
{
    int i = low, j = mid+1 , k = low;
    string Temp[50000]; //<--- Allocation happens every time this function is called
```

Wnenever MergeA is called, 50000 `string`s are constructed & destructed every time, encumbering the algorithm. Just add `static` there:

```
void MergeA(int low ,int mid , int high)
{
    int i = low, j = mid+1 , k = low;
    static string Temp[50000]; //Now it is constructed & destructed only once in the program
```

Comment: `thread_local static`?

Comment: While this is just single-threaded implementation, just `static` will be enough.